# Mesos failing to deploy container with same spec after destroying initial application

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon, dcos

I am using marathon to deploy my containers on mesos cluster. My marathon spec is as

```
 {
  "id": "app-name",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 2,
  "mem": 6500,
  "disk": 34000,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "docker": {
      "image": "path-to-private-docker-registry",
      "network": "HOST",
      "privileged": true,
      "forcePullImage": true,
      "parameters": [
        {
          "key": "log-driver",
          "value": "none"
        },
        {
          "key": "oom-kill-disable",
          "value": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "volumes": [
      {
        "containerPath": "/app/logs",
        "hostPath": "/home/ubuntu/app/logs",
        "mode": "RW"
      }
    ],
    "type": "DOCKER"
  }
}
```

Initial deployment is successful. But after some days when I rebuild my docker image with changes in it and try to redeploy the application it does not result in a success. Some logs that I was able to salvage are:

marathon logs :

```
   [2016-06-27 20:24:19,658] INFO Received offers NOT WANTED notification, canceling 2 revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13)
[2016-06-27 20:24:19,659] INFO Finished processing fd99193f-56a9-4653-ab8e-4b2d86d048a0-O20. Matched 1 ops after 2 passes. ports(*) 8000->8568,8570->9000,31000->32000; mem(*) 459.0; disk(*) 11140.0 left. (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15)
[2016-06-27 20:24:19,659] INFO Processing LaunchEphemeral(LaunchedEphemeral(task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5],AgentInfo(ip-172-30-2-84,Some(abd14501-6f19-4443-b5f3-22a44a2f3d4f-S3),Buffer()),2016-06-27T14:53:52.324Z,Status(2016-06-27T14:54:19.657Z,None,None),Vector(8569))) for task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launcher.impl.OfferProcessorImpl:ForkJoinPool-2-worker-13)
[2016-06-27 20:24:19,667] INFO receiveTaskUpdate: updating status of task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5] (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2016-06-27 20:24:19,667] INFO Task launch for 'task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5]' was accepted. 0 tasksToLaunch, 0 in flight, 1 confirmed.  not backing off (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2016-06-27 20:24:22,362] INFO 111.93.51.122 - - [27/Jun/2016:14:54:22 +0000] "GET //52.76.213.44:7070/v2/deployments HTTP/1.1" 200 364 "<marathon-webui>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"  (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog$$EnhancerByGuice$$38de1910:qtp1620041759-33)
[2016-06-27 20:24:22,368] INFO 111.93.51.122 - - [27/Jun/2016:14:54:22 +0000] "GET //52.76.213.44:7070/v2/groups?embed=group.groups&embed=group.apps&embed=group.apps.deployments&embed=group.apps.counts&embed=group.apps.readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 1247 "<marathon-webui>" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"  (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog$$EnhancerByGuice$$38de1910:qtp1620041759-36)
[2016-06-27 20:24:22,467] INFO 111.93.51.122 - - [27/Jun/2016:14:54:22 +0000] "GET //52.76.213.44:7070/v2/queue HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "http://<marathon-webui>/ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"  (mesosphere.chaos.http.ChaosRequestLog$$EnhancerByGuice$$38de1910:qtp1620041759-31)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,372] INFO Received status update for task application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5: TASK_FAILED (Docker container run error: Container exited on error: exited with status 125) (mesosphere.marathon.MarathonScheduler$$EnhancerByGuice$$388f7d52:Thread-44)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,379] INFO Removed app [/application] from tracker (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.tracker.TaskTracker$TasksByApp$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,380] INFO Increasing delay. Task launch delay for [/application] changed from [0 milliseconds] to [1 seconds]. (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.RateLimiter$:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,381] INFO receiveTaskUpdate: task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5] finished (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,382] INFO Sending event notification for task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5] of app [/application]: TASK_FAILED (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.PostToEventStreamStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$1cb38257:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,382] WARN New task [task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5]] failed during app /application scaling, queueing another task (mesosphere.marathon.upgrade.TaskStartActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,382] INFO initiating a scale check for app [/application] after task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5] terminated (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$d6da0d15:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-06-27 20:24:25,382] INFO schedulerActor: Actor[akka://marathon/user/MarathonScheduler#513692909] (mesosphere.marathon.core.task.update.impl.steps.ScaleAppUpdateStepImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$d6da0d15:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,401] INFO activating matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actor[akka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/1-application#492133230]). (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,401] INFO Received offers WANTED notification (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,401] INFO => revive offers NOW, canceling any scheduled revives (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,402] INFO 2 further revives still needed. Repeating reviveOffers according to --revive_offers_repetitions 3 (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,402] INFO => Schedule next revive at 2016-06-27T14:54:31.401Z in 5000 milliseconds, adhering to --min_revive_offers_interval 5000 (ms) (mesosphere.marathon.core.flow.impl.ReviveOffersActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,407] INFO Request Launch for task 'application.0af6311a-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5', version '2016-06-27T14:53:52.324Z'. 1 tasksToLaunch, 0 in flight, 0 confirmed.  not backing off (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,407] INFO No tasks left to launch. Stop receiving offers for /application, 2016-06-27T14:53:52.324Z (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13)
[2016-06-27 20:24:26,407] INFO removing matcher ActorOfferMatcher(Actor[akka://marathon/user/launchQueue/1/1-application#492133230]) (mesosphere.marathon.core.matcher.manager.impl.OfferMatcherManagerActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13)
```

Interestingly, marathon is getting much less resources like memory and disk space from mesos-master when all these resources are available.

mesos-slave logs:

```
I0627 20:19:33.232674 12123 slave.cpp:1520] Got assigned task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:19:33.234148 12120 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/slaves/d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0/frameworks/ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000' from gc
I0627 20:19:33.234454 12120 gc.cpp:83] Unscheduling '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0/frameworks/ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000' from gc
I0627 20:19:33.234699 12122 slave.cpp:1639] Launching task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:19:33.236215 12122 paths.cpp:528] Trying to chown '/tmp/mesos/slaves/d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0/frameworks/ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000/executors/application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5/runs/89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69' to user 'ubuntu'
I0627 20:19:33.238883 12122 slave.cpp:5644] Launching executor application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 with resources cpus(*):0.1; mem(*):32 in work directory '/tmp/mesos/slaves/d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0/frameworks/ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000/executors/application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5/runs/89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69'
I0627 20:19:33.239861 12122 slave.cpp:1865] Queuing task 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' for executor 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:19:33.242758 12122 docker.cpp:1011] Starting container '89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69' for task 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' (and executor 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5') of framework 'ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000'
I0627 20:19:33.436872 12121 docker.cpp:627] Checkpointing pid 12462 to '/tmp/mesos/meta/slaves/d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0/frameworks/ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000/executors/application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5/runs/89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69/pids/forked.pid'
I0627 20:19:33.495285 12127 slave.cpp:2860] Got registration for executor 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 from executor(1)@172.30.2.145:59715
I0627 20:19:33.496909 12127 docker.cpp:1322] Ignoring updating container '89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69' with resources passed to update is identical to existing resources
I0627 20:19:33.497323 12127 slave.cpp:2030] Sending queued task 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' to executor 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 at executor(1)@172.30.2.145:59715
I0627 20:19:38.940521 12126 slave.cpp:3219] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 433ac498-3926-4e81-ae3b-d8701a5f6963) for task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 from executor(1)@172.30.2.145:59715
E0627 20:19:38.972251 12127 slave.cpp:3469] Failed to update resources for container 89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69 of executor 'application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5' running task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 on status update for terminal task, destroying container: Failed to 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock inspect mesos-d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0.89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69': exit status = exited with status 1 stderr = Error: No such image or container: mesos-d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0.89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69
I0627 20:19:38.972554 12127 status_update_manager.cpp:320] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 433ac498-3926-4e81-ae3b-d8701a5f6963) for task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:19:38.972686 12124 docker.cpp:1731] Destroying container '89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69'
I0627 20:19:38.972718 12124 docker.cpp:1817] Sending SIGTERM to executor with pid: 12462
I0627 20:19:38.977213 12127 status_update_manager.cpp:824] Checkpointing UPDATE for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 433ac498-3926-4e81-ae3b-d8701a5f6963) for task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:19:38.981940 12121 slave.cpp:3617] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 433ac498-3926-4e81-ae3b-d8701a5f6963) for task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 to master@172.30.2.96:5050
I0627 20:19:38.982400 12121 slave.cpp:3527] Sending acknowledgement for status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 433ac498-3926-4e81-ae3b-d8701a5f6963) for task application.c04407a4-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 to executor(1)@172.30.2.145:59715
I0627 20:19:38.986201 12124 docker.cpp:1859] Running docker stop on container '89668c43-35ac-4a55-976c-a66481296f69'
I0627 20:19:38.988855 12123 slave.cpp:3745] executor(1)@172.30.2.145:59715 exited
```

mesos-master logs:

```
I0627 20:21:25.094447  5875 master.cpp:4829] Re-registered agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145) with ports(*):[8000-9000, 31000-32000]; cpus(*):2; mem(*):6959; disk(*):45140
I0627 20:21:25.094547  5875 master.cpp:4864] Sending updated checkpointed resources  to agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145)
I0627 20:21:25.094853  5872 hierarchical.cpp:473] Added agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 (ip-172-30-2-145) with ports(*):[8000-9000, 31000-32000]; cpus(*):2; mem(*):6959; disk(*):45140 (allocated: )
I0627 20:21:25.096194  5873 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 2.77403ms
I0627 20:21:25.096230  5873 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 961
I0627 20:21:25.097221  5872 master.cpp:4926] Received update of agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145) with total oversubscribed resources 
I0627 20:21:25.097904  5872 hierarchical.cpp:531] Agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 (ip-172-30-2-145) updated with oversubscribed resources  (total: ports(*):[8000-9000, 31000-32000]; cpus(*):2; mem(*):6959; disk(*):45140, allocated: )
I0627 20:21:25.098150  5870 replica.cpp:691] Replica received learned notice for position 961 from @0.0.0.0:0
I0627 20:21:25.100486  5870 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 2.302917ms
I0627 20:21:25.100553  5870 leveldb.cpp:399] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 32386ns
I0627 20:21:25.100579  5870 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 961
I0627 20:21:25.100605  5870 replica.cpp:697] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 961
I0627 20:21:25.803926  5868 http.cpp:313] HTTP GET for /master/state from 111.93.51.122:4363 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
I0627 20:21:33.465710  5868 master.cpp:2465] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:21:33.466069  5868 master.cpp:2541] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0627 20:21:33.467990  5868 hierarchical.cpp:264] Added framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:21:33.469707  5868 master.cpp:5632] Sending 1 offers to framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:21:33.622820  5872 master.cpp:3949] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ fd99193f-56a9-4653-ab8e-4b2d86d048a0-O0 ] for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:21:35.989673  5874 http.cpp:313] HTTP GET for /master/state from 111.93.51.122:60515 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
I0627 20:21:47.045994  5872 http.cpp:313] HTTP GET for /master/state from 111.93.51.122:4363 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
I0627 20:21:48.465175  5875 master.cpp:5305] Performing implicit task state reconciliation for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:21:58.040252  5874 http.cpp:313] HTTP GET for /master/state from 111.93.51.122:60515 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
I0627 20:22:02.247869  5869 master.cpp:4028] Processing REVIVE call for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:22:02.248029  5869 hierarchical.cpp:989] Removed offer filters for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:22:02.249119  5869 master.cpp:5632] Sending 1 offers to framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:22:02.414969  5869 master.cpp:3412] Processing ACCEPT call for offers: [ fd99193f-56a9-4653-ab8e-4b2d86d048a0-O1 ] on agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145) for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:22:02.418418  5871 master.hpp:177] Adding task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 with resources cpus(*):2; mem(*):6500; disk(*):32000; ports(*):[8488-8488] on agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 (ip-172-30-2-145)
I0627 20:22:02.418742  5871 master.cpp:3897] Launching task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020 with resources cpus(*):2; mem(*):6500; disk(*):32000; ports(*):[8488-8488] on agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145)
I0627 20:22:03.241605  5873 master.cpp:5632] Sending 1 offers to framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:22:03.244705  5874 master.cpp:3949] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ fd99193f-56a9-4653-ab8e-4b2d86d048a0-O2 ] for framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-18a0602a-d587-4395-8eef-b63050d3f1e8@172.30.2.96:37020
I0627 20:22:09.048271  5870 http.cpp:313] HTTP GET for /master/state from 111.93.51.122:4363 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
I0627 20:22:20.003542  5869 master.cpp:5071] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 41eb819c-d132-4449-8a97-c6a9751514c7) for task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 from agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145)
I0627 20:22:20.003643  5869 master.cpp:5119] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 41eb819c-d132-4449-8a97-c6a9751514c7) for task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000
I0627 20:22:20.004073  5869 master.cpp:6727] Updating the state of task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 (latest state: TASK_FAILED, status update state: TASK_FAILED)
```

So what could be the problem here?? I don't seem to get it work after initial deployment.

Furthermore, I have tested my new docker container using docker run and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Marathon launched the task here:

```
[2016-06-27 20:24:19,667] INFO Task launch for 'task [application.06f03939-3c77-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5]' was accepted. 0 tasksToLaunch, 0 in flight, 1 confirmed.  not backing off (mesosphere.marathon.core.launchqueue.impl.AppTaskLauncherActor:marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16)
```

It looks like the task was dispatched by Marathon just fine.

The task (or one just like it) actually fails here:

```
I0627 20:22:20.003542  5869 master.cpp:5071] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 41eb819c-d132-4449-8a97-c6a9751514c7) for task application.b50fd5d3-3c76-11e6-963c-e2736a05f0b5 of framework ce1d562f-9cfd-494e-8e23-b7e0fa4110f2-0000 from agent d2a2a152-aa17-4e21-8af4-b5e5e91cf770-S0 at slave(1)@172.30.2.145:5051 (ip-172-30-2-145)
```

You can check the Mesos Sandbox to look for Docker logs in the stdout/stderr files.